# Azure Kubernetes Failover with PersistentVolumes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, azure-disk

I am currently testing how Azure Kubernetes handles failover for StatefulSets. I simulated a network partition by running `sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP` on one of my nodes, not perfect but good enough to test some things.

1). How can I reuse disks that are mounted to a failed node? Is there a way to manually release the disk and make it available to the rescheduled pod? It takes forever for the resources to be released after doing a force delete, sometimes this takes over an hour.

2). If I delete a node from the cluster all the resources are released after a certain amount of time. The problem is that in the Azure dashboard it still displays my cluster as using 3 nodes even if I have deleted one. Is there a way to manually add the deleted node back in or do I need to rebuild the cluster each time?

3). I most definitely do not want to use `ReadWriteMany`.

Basically what I want is for my StatefulSet pods to terminate and have the associated disks detach and then reschedule on a new node in the event of a network partition or a node failure. I know the pods will terminate in the event of a recovery from a network partition but I want control over the process myself or at least have it happen sooner.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, just detach the disks manually from the portal (or powershell\cli\api\etc)
2. This is not supported, you should not do this. Scaling\Upgrading might fix this, but it might not
3. Okay, dont.